# "Actions must be plain objects" ... but it is

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-thunk, redux-mock-store

Sorry very common error, but in the test below don't understand how the offending action `storeMgrAnnouncement(result)` is not a plain object.  The api call and the thunk action are mocked, but the offending action isn't.

**home.test.js**

```
/* not showing 3rd party imports */

import Home from '../../components/home';
import {getMgrAnnouncement} from "../../__mocks__/actions";
import {STORE_MGR_ANNOUNCEMENT} from "../../constants";
import {success} from "../../__fixtures__/announcementGet";

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

describe('Home Page', () => {

    var store = null;
    const initialState = {};

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        shallow(<Home store={store} />);
    });

    it ('should store manager announcement after retrieving it', async () => {
        await store.dispatch(getMgrAnnouncement());
        expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual({
            type: STORE_MGR_ANNOUNCEMENT, 
            payload: success
        });
    });
```

**__mocks__/actions/index.js**

```
import { storeMgrAnnouncement } from '../../actions';
import { success } from '../../__fixtures__/announcementGet';

/* mock api call */
function announcementGet() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      resolve(success)
    })
  })
}

/* mock thunk action */
export function getMgrAnnouncement() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return announcementGet()
    .then(result => {
      /*
         ERROR: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
      */
      dispatch(storeMgrAnnouncement(result));
    })
  }
}
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import { STORE_MGR_ANNOUNCEMENT } from '../../constants';

export function storeMgrAnnouncement(result) {
  return {
    type: STORE_MGR_ANNOUNCEMENT,
    payload: result
  }
}
```

Comment: I voted to close this question as no longer reproducible, since the OP posted a comment to the provided answer suggesting that they solved the problem and it was unrelated to the code posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching the result of getMgrAnnouncement()

```
store.dispatch(getMgrAnnouncement())
```

But that function returns a function:

```
function getMgrAnnouncement() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
```

You must dispatch an object, not a function.

Comment: thanks for the response.  But that function is a thunk, so it's supposed to return a function, which should be handled by the thunk middleware.  Regardless,I think I found my problem, which is unrelated.